# catching only local AttributeError (when checking if method exist and calling it)

Tags: python, exception

What is the most "pythonic" way of catching `AttributeError` only for a missing method, not `AttributeError` from code within a subsequent call to that method? I have this code, which tries to call a method, and provide some actions in case of missing method or some expected exceptions:

```
def foo(unknown_object):
    try:
        unknown_object.do_something()
    except SomeSpecificError:
        # the method existed, but failed in some expected way
    except AttributeError:
        # do something else ...
```

This has the problem of also catching `AttributeError` from running `do_something()`, for example programming errors (spelling some attribute wrong). This is obviously not very good for debugging, and catching too much is probably a bug in itself. I could rewrite it into:

```
def foo(unknown_object):
    try:
        method=unknown_object.do_something
    except AttributeError:
        # do something else ...
    else:
        try:
            method()
        except SomeSpecificError:
            # the method existed, but failed in some expected way
```

but is this nested solution the most pythonic way of avoiding catching too many`AttributeError`?

Notice : The method is either missing or callable (or it's a programming error which should raise uncaught exceptions), so I don't need checking call-ability.

Answer (score 0):

If you  really want to check for something that specific then you can use the hasattr and callable method

```
if hasattr(unknown_object, "do_something") and callable(unknown_object.do_something):
    unknown_object.do_something()
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now. Or (using plain symbols instead of the string needed for hasattr) a try : foo.attr except AttributeError: pass else : foo.attr(). But it still seems like wasteful duplication.